# Fastest way to create checkboxes

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, client-side

I have a Google Chrome extension that creates a select-all function for a search engine, but it is slow (1-14 seconds, 250-1000 results) is there a faster way to do this? My code is below:

```
var dropdownvalue = dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value;
if ((dropdownvalue == "createFullCheckboxes") || (dropdownvalue == "createNameCheckboxes")) {
    var div_embed1 = document.getElementById('results-pane');

    if (div_embed1) {
        div_embed1.innerHTML = '<form id="checkbox-form">' + div_embed1.innerHTML + '</form>';
    }

    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName('name');

    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].innerHTML = '<input id="checkbox" type="checkbox">' + x[i].innerHTML + '';
    }

    checkedAll();
    return;
}​
```

I tried changing the for loop to this: `for (var i = 0, len = x.length; i < len; i++){` but there was only a 20ms difference. `CheckedAll()` is a function that simply selects all of the checkboxes.

The other part (not shown) that loops through the selected checkboxes and actually makes the select-all work is much faster at 92ms and even for 1000 results it is still fast.

Here is a snip from the chrome dev tools:

[image: Snapshot of the timings]

Thank you.

Comment: its the dom access that is slow, not your loop. the loop is insignificant compared to dom operations. you would would have to refactor with an array.push for strings, then join at the end and place one big text result into the dom one time

Comment: I thought that it was the DOM but did not see a different way, could you please explain in more detail?
Thank you.

Comment: you are going through dom each loop iteration. instead, if it were possible to create your html in entirety as if you can draw a square around the large area you are defining, that is the approach. you would have to show your dom in your example for me to show a specific approach based on how you render

Comment: I can't copy-and-paste from the page or create a demo as it is too complex and a very expensive paid service.
But, do you have a demo of something similar?
Thank you.

Comment: ok well sorry, that is a cop out. if you can't put a small snippet on the page, then sorry, not worth answering. that is necessary. firefox inspect just gives you the html portion from the dom area you are looking at. there is really no excuse these days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would test:

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName('name');
var h = '<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox">';
var i = x.length;
while(i--){ x[i].innerHTML = h + x[i].innerHTML; }
```

the equal test should be faster than the less than test.

Try a Duffs Device:(speculative as we do not know the markup render and the prototype properties that might impact negatively)(NOTE removed the id= to avoid duplicate ID) replaced with class)

```
function process(xi, h) {
    xi.innerHTML = h + xi.innerHTML;
}
var x = document.getElementsByClassName('name');
var h = '<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox">';
var iterations = Math.floor(x.length / 8);
var leftover = x.length % 8;
var i = 0;

if (leftover > 0) {
    do {
        process(x[i++], h);
    } while (--leftover > 0);
}

do {
    process(x[i++], h);
    process(x[i++], h);
    process(x[i++], h);
    process(x[i++], h);
    process(x[i++], h);
    process(x[i++], h);
    process(x[i++], h);
    process(x[i++], h);
} while (--iterations > 0);
```

Comment: As noted in a comment, this is minor compared to the DOM access which your performance test notes.

Comment: I also tested the method from: [Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/javascript-dom) and it is faster, but you still get the credit for supplying a very easy to understand and easy-to-implement answer, thank you very much.